# how to remove the close button from popupkeyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am customizing the android keyboard after downloading the sample keyboard code from `developer.android.com`. I want to customize the layout of the popup window after a user made a long press on a given key, `onLongPress(key popupKey)`. Particularly, I want to get ridoff the close button at the end of the popup keys and want to make the window close when the user clicks outside it. But, I can't figure out how to get access to the popup window. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figure it out myself and want to share for anyone interested.
I was not able to get the close button and get rid off it. But, what I got easier is creating a PopupWindow having multiple buttons whose labels are the popup characters taken from the key parameter passed to onLongPress(). 
This way I was able to display only the popup characters and close the window when the user selects on of them or presses outside of the window.

Cheers!